# Why is my dalgona coffee foamy instead of creamy?

Tags: iced-coffee, foamed-milk, dalgona

A dalgona coffee with cold milk is my go-to summer drink. I discovered this golden coffee beauty during the last summer lockdown and since then did not stop drinking it.
Since I started last year I am following the same recipe:

> 2 tbsp instant coffee or espresso powder
> 1 tbsp sugar
> 2 tbsp very hot water
> ca. 300ml/13fl oz milk

Mixing the ingredients above except the milk with a hand mixer.

(slightly changed recipe from https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/dalonga_coffee_20606)

Usually, my dalgona cream always had a very creamy texture, almost like whipped cream, see below:

[image: creamy dagona coffee]

But the last two times, my coffee cream got frothy, like a milk foam instead. I know that reduced sugar can lead to more frothy and less creamy foam, but as said, I did follow the exact same recipe.

Any idea why the foam is not creamy anymore? And I get a froth instead? Could this be due to mixing it on a higher/quicker level?

I would like to have my coffee cream back. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome! It seems you have baffled the community? Did you change anything, e.g. another brand of instant coffee, another kind of sugar? Different whipping speed or different mixer?

Comment: Thank you! :) Unfortunately, I didn’t. I recognized that it seems like the cream turns into a froth after a min or so. Now that I think about it, I used the last times plastic bowl and might have used a metal bowl before to mix the cream. Could that be it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any idea why the foam is not creamy anymore? And I get a froth instead? **Could this be due to mixing it on a higher/quicker level?**

Yes, absolutely. Rudimentary speaking the process of whipping something is adhering air bubbles to the fats in your mix (similar to soap bubbles, where the fats act as the soap). The finer these air bubbles are, the finer and more creamy the mixture appears. If you whack it at high speed, it will create large air pockets, which at the next time the whisk comes around at speed either collapse, or create more large air bubbles. Mixing at lower speeds will create smaller bubbles, which at next rotation can subdivide into smaller and smaller bubbles, giving you the smooth consistency you're looking for.

Don't go too low though, as you'll just be stirring the mixture instead and not incorporating any air. The best way to create the right consistency is doing so on a "medium" setting taking roughly 5-6 minutes to whip up your coffee (or longer depending on the amount of mix, more mix takes more time).

Comment: Thank you again! After following your advice, I think it's been a combination out of the higher mixing and plastic bowl. I mixed this time on a lower level in a metal bowl and got my coffee cream back!